# Hash data via HmacSHA512 returns error when call external API

Tags: java, api, http, hash, hmac

I am trying to use this `API` [bitmarket](https://github.com/bitmarket-net/api)

First I would like to call basic method `info` that's why in `postman` I added to headers to fields:

- `API-Key` -> my api key
- `API-Hash` -> my hash which is generated below) via `HMAC SHA512` signature.

How I generate `API-Hash`?
I have written in `Java` simple method which looks like:

```
  public String encodeDataViaHMAC(String msg, String keyString, String algo) {
        String digest = null;
        try {
            SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec((keyString).getBytes("UTF-8"), algo);
            Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(algo);
            mac.init(key);

            byte[] bytes = mac.doFinal(msg.getBytes("ASCII"));

            StringBuffer hash = new StringBuffer();
            for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
                String hex = Integer.toHexString(0xFF & bytes[i]);
                if (hex.length() == 1) {
                    hash.append('0');
                }
                hash.append(hex);
            }
            digest = hash.toString();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        }
        return digest;
    }
```

and then I pass to it parameters:

- map of request parameters:

`Map<String, Object> m = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    m.put("method", "info");
    m.put("tonce", System.currentTimeMillis());`

- private key
- method name which is `HmacSHA512`

and after that I still get it `postman` error:

```
{"error":502,"errorMsg":"Invalid message hash","time":1514023708}
```

Does anyone can help what am I doing wrong and can help me to fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compute HMAC-SHA512 with secret key in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39355241/compute-hmac-sha512-with-secret-key-in-java)

Comment: I tried this. Doesn’t work also..

Comment: HMAC keys are usually not Strings. Make sure you interpret the key and the data correctly (hex, base64 or any other encoding has to be decoded first).