# How are jwt digest and java's secret key linked?

Tags: java, jwt

I have a keystore where I have to insert a key to encode/decode my jwts.
I know that jwts can be created by using many alghorithms (in my case I would have to use hmac-sha512) but how this relates to java secret key?

Could you please show me how to generare a secret key on the fly, what requirements it should have?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
    SecretKey generateSecretKey(String algorithmName, int keySize)
        throws Exception {
    KeyGenerator keygen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("HmacSHA512");
    keygen.init(keySize);

    return keygen.generateKey();
}
```

You can also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39355241/compute-hmac-sha512-with-secret-key-in-java).